# Vim UltiSnips '<c-k>' doesn't work and return "?" mark

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, ultisnips

these are lines in my .vimrc to map UltiSnips plugin:

```
let g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger="<c-j>"
let g:UltiSnipsJumpForwardTrigger="<c-j>"
let g:UltiSnipsJumpBackwardTrigger="<c-k>"
```

Ctrl+j it's work well to expand trigger and jump forward, but when press Ctrl+k to jump backward it does't work and return question mark in cursor like this:

```
function() {
   ?
}
```

Also try change jump backward to Ctrl+l still doesn't work and return ^L in cursor:

```
function() {
  ^L
}
```

VIM version is 7.4 with patches: 1-682, compiled it from source
my shell is Zsh

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you reach the $0 tabstop, you can no longer jump back: the snippet is exited.

```
function ${1:function_name}() {
        ${0:#function_body}
}
```

It works with other snippets. try `case`